# Return give me always true

Tags: php, function, oop

Guys i have this code:

```
class Test {

public function __construct($valore) {

    if ($valore != TRUE ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

  }
}
```

and in another page this:

```
$test = new Test("");

if ($test) {
echo "result is: TRUE";
} else {
echo "result is: FALSE";
}
```

Why is all the time true??
Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's always true because the $test object is always NOT false, it's an object. The return value of the constructor isn't what you're testing.

```
class Test {
var $valore;
public function __construct($valore) {

    if ($valore != TRUE ) {
        $this->valore = false;
    } else {
        $this->valore = true;
    }

  }
}

$test = new Test(FALSE);

if ($test->valore === TRUE) {
echo "result is: TRUE";
} else {
echo "result is: FALSE";
}
```

Comment: FYI, using `var` in classes has been deprecated for along time and shouldn't be used in new code. Use `public`, `protected`, or `private`.

Comment: Are you trying to overcompensate now because your original answer was wrong, I pointed that out, and now you've taken my answer and are claiming it be your's? Pretty petty.

Comment: I agree. I actually haven't use var in a member variable declaration in a long time, not sure why I did here. But I'll leave it along with our discussion about it so that it serves as informative for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors don't have return values. So if you want a to test that value you need to have a method do this for you.

```
class Test 
{
    private $valore;

    public function __construct($valore) {
        $this->valore = $valore;
    }

    public function test() {
        return (bool) $valore;
    }
}

$test = new Test("");

if ($test->test()) {
    echo "result is: TRUE";
} else {
    echo "result is: FALSE";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/291115)

Comment: The questioner is testing if the $test object is "true" or "false." The value returned from the constructor is not actually what they are checking in their code. What they are checking, the $test object, will always been seen by PHP as true. The $valore variable is not actually be tested in their executing code. In other words, the return value from the constructor is not going to be assigned to $test.

Comment: That's kind of lame to jack my answer and make it your own. Whateves.

Comment: Actually I didn't even review your answer. But it does show that it is correct. And mine does not use obsolete code. :)